# Flutter background Api fetch

Tags: flutter, dart

Actually I was trying to implement background process (fetch data from api) even the app is terminated in my flutter project how can I achieve in both Android & iOS platforms.

Comment: it's possible upto android 11 and in ios it's not possible

Comment: Hi @Joel, if app is terminated you couldn't make any actions, at least in android. The only way to achieve it is to use foreground service. Read 'services' on android developers site. Libraries for flutter: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task, https://pub.dev/packages/foreground_service

Comment: Or he could use work schedulers. But I didn't find any library related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever wanted to execute Dart code in the background—even if your app wasn’t the currently active app?

> The mechanism for this feature involves setting up an isolate.
> Isolates are Dart’s model for multithreading, though an isolate
> differs from a conventional thread in that it doesn’t share memory
> with the main program. You’ll set up your isolate for background
> execution using callbacks and a callback dispatcher.

[Example](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124)

but if you want do that when app terminated, you will have to wakeup app through [Workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) or some another approach like sending firebase push notification or wakeup app in scheduled time with flutter alarm manager or something like that